How to pass matrix as input to matlab function from .net app?
I want to pass matrix as input from .net app to matlab function
Matlab function:
function myfunc(info);
   sort(info)
end


I want info input be recieved in function like this:
info = [...
            0   0   0;  ... 
            0   120 0;  ... 
            240 120 0;  ... 
            240 0   0;  ... 
            ];

and .net code:
MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();

matlab.Execute(@"cd C:\scripts\myfunc.m");

object result = null;

int[,] input = new int[4, 3] { { 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 120, 0 }, { 240, 120, 0 }, { 240, 0, 0 } };

matlab.Feval("myfunc", 0, out result, input);


This gives me error in Feval line--> "error using norm first argument must be single or double."
And when I change input to be like this
int[,,] input = new int[4, 1, 3] {
    { {0, 0, 0} },
    { {0, 120, 0} },
    { {240, 120, 0} },
    { {240, 0, 0} }
};

It gives another error --> 'index in position 1 exceeds array bounds. index must not exceed 1
How to solve this?

I'm pretty sure MATLAB requires you to pass either floats or doubles, i.e. single/ double precision floating point numbers. At least all the examples I've seen use double arrays, the error message also points in that direction.

The error message "error using norm first argument must be single or double" pretty clearly indicates that your array has to be float or double rather than int. Have you tried double[,] input = new double[...] ...?
